# Inconsistent preview and rendered image (rendered image is completely bright)

Tags: rendering, error

Preview

[image]

Rendered image

[image]

The light pipe is modeled with an emissive shader and the background is a yellowish low-res picture. The image is a screenshot when the final rendering is still running, so no composition/post-processing is applied. Everything seems to be right until I turn the light pipe on with the emissive shader. What might be the problem with this issue?

Comment: Need more info but off the top of my head, I'd say you restricted rendering on parts of the image or you're using layers.

Comment: Your image is not bright, it is just your building is not being rendered

Comment: Ah, I'm an idiot. How could I just turned every object off...